# how to know about token implementation?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rust, substrate-node, pallet-contracts

I have a questions about Tokens in polkadot ecosystem , If I am on parachain and this parachain A uses a token from another parachain B , if this token implements on_transfer hook does this hook will operate on the parachain A or it will be deactivated ?
and I want to ask if the on_transfer hook can be implemented by tokens  in polkadot by any substrate pallet ?

Comment: which `on_transfer` hook are you referring to?